# Как получить абсолютно все переменные GET-запроса в php?

Tags: php, get

Пробовал так, но это не работает:

```
<?php
$str = "";
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $str .= $key . " - " . $value . PHP_EOL;
}
echo $str;
?>
```

UPD (Решение): Таким образом переменные не получить, нужно парсить $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']

```
<?php
$str = "";
$query  = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
foreach($query as $param)
{
    list($name, $value) = explode('=', $param, 2);
    $str = $str . $value . PHP_EOL;
}
echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: как именно "но это не работает" ?

Comment: Пример запроса что отсылаете на сервер и пример вывода на сервере. Добавьте это в вопрос

Comment: Время изобретать велосипеды.

Comment: `parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);` в помощь )

Comment: explode обладает фатальным недостатком - его написали не вы. Надо переписать.

Comment: `$_GET` чем Вас ну устраивает?

Comment: Тем, что я не знаю, что мне за переменные передают. Код, который я изначально привёл (с использованием $_GET), выдаст только последнее значение переменной.

Comment: Если передавать `?a=2&a=3&a=4`, то конечно нужны костыли.

Comment: Я, конечно, прошу прощения, но как-то по-другому можно передавать GET-запрос?

Comment: `?a[]=2&a[]=3&a[]=4` и в `$_GET[a]` будет внезапно __массив__

Comment: Спасибо за ликбез, я не знаю php просто, пишу программу для десктопа, и мне понадобилась функция сохранения пользовательской информации в текстовый файл на сервере построчно вида "имя_переменной|значение".

Comment: Вообще, похоже, придётся использовать костыли. Иначе так не реализовать. У пользователя также должна присутствовать "прозрачность" составления запроса вручную, поэтому и обрабатываю GET. При передаче массива потеряется имя переменной. Хотя, возможно, стоит взглянуть в сторону сериализации, но тоже в этом не спец.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение простое

```php
preg_match_all("/(\w+)\=(\w+)[&]?/", parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['query'], $matches );
var_dump( $matches );
```

На примере `URL`-а вида `?utm_source=1e&utm_content=2&utm_campaign=3&utm_term=4`

> результат

```php
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'utm_source=1e&' (length=14)
      1 => string 'utm_content=2&' (length=14)
      2 => string 'utm_campaign=3&' (length=15)
      3 => string 'utm_term=4' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'utm_source' (length=10)
      1 => string 'utm_content' (length=11)
      2 => string 'utm_campaign' (length=12)
      3 => string 'utm_term' (length=8)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '1e' (length=2)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '3' (length=1)
      3 => string '4' (length=1)
```

Comment: А вот это действительно красивое решение. Спасибо!

Comment: Поправлю немного свое же решение. Паттерн `([^=]+)\=([^&]+)` будет более правильным для разбора `URL`

Comment: А вот так - `[?&]([^=]+)\=([^&]+)` - еще правильнее :)